# Compare Multiple Integers and find largest in java

Tags: java, list, int

I am kind of new to java, and I am making a MAbovePixel Generator. Right now my idea is that the very top pixels, and the very right pixels are blue, from then on the generator has a chance of making yellow(sand), then from there, ground, and grass.

So far, I have the 'generator' check the pixel above it, and the left of it. Depending on what color the pixel is, the current pixel has a chance of being one of the pixels next to it.

```
          if (LeftPixel == 0xFF0000FF) OceanChance = OceanChance + 5;
          if (AbovePixel == 0xFF0000FF) OceanChance = OceanChance + 5;
          if (LeftPixel == 0xFFEDC9AF) SandChance = SandChance + 5;
          if (AbovePixel == 0xFFEDC9AF) SandChance = SandChance + 5;
          if (LeftPixel == 0xFF733D1A) GroundChance = GroundChance + 5;
          if (AbovePixel == 0xFF733D1A) GroundChance = GroundChance + 5;
          if (LeftPixel == 0xFF698B22) GrassChance = GrassChance + 5;
          if (AbovePixel == 0xFF698B22) GrassChance = GrassChance + 5;
```

At this point, I am unsure what to do next.
I have the list, but how do I check whats largest in Java?

How do I compare all the ints in the list, and depending on whats largest, do whatever.
Or if theres a tie, randomly select a int to use anyway from a list of ties.

I did search on the internet "Java compare multiple integers", but it didn't come up with anything I could understand, so maybe theres a name for what im trying to do that I don't know about?

In any case, what is the best thing to do?

Comment: You don't appear to have a list or an array. Can you simplify your example to just have what you need to for the question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I think I simplified it a bit.

Comment: It seems you don't have a straight forward algorithm to go with. Can you explain what you want to do clearer? Also never give short names to your variables. No one will be going to get what these magic names mean.

Comment: Out of the list, I want to take the sum of all the Chances, and see which is larger. Of course, right now they would all be the same right now, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 4 Chance integers and you need to find the largest? If so put them in a sorted list `TreeSet` and get the last element in the list

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the list and find the maximum. If it's only 4 values you can write 4 if's comparing each one with the current maximum, although java jitter probably does just that.

edit:

or just use  Collections#max()

Comment: I was planning on adding ALOT of values to the list. Maybe around..40? Working on a game, the pixels will be the tiles. So it'll be a very large list at the end of it all.

Comment: still if it's only about finding max you should iterate the list. There is no faster and simpler way.

Comment: alertnatively if you don't care about position in the list you should use Collections#max(), edited the answer